# Transfer encoding not supported

Tags: php, php-curl

Recently i faced a problem with connecting to proxmox api. code

```
$ch=curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://myhost:8006/api2/json/access/ticket");
     $pf = 'username='. urlencode($username).'@pve&password='.urlencode($password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pf);
   curl_exec($ch)
```

works fine.

but

```
$ch=curl_init();
$put_post_heareds[]="CSRFPreventionToken: {$mytokenhere}";
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://myhost:8006/api2/json/nodes/ps116/qemu/118/status/stop");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $put_post_headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "PVEAuthCookie="{$mycookiedata}");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_exec($ch);
```

returns 501 chunked transfer encoding not supported

maybe someone can help with this?

i tried to add
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [])`,
tried to set
`$put_post_http_headers[]="Expect:";` (as i found on php.net)

tried to set `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);` as chunked is http1.1 feature...
nothing helps

p.s php8.2. i found that on php7.4 all worked fine. but still can't find difference...

as answer to comments:

i tried curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ''); - nothing
that post at proxmox forum is mine.

yes, today i found solution. replaced
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);` with `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");`

but why this happens? i cant find anything related in php docs...

i changed code with all semicolons.
i googled a lot about disabling chunking, maybe i missed something

Comment: I did find a similar question, probably asked by you, here: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/error-chunked-transfer-encoding-not-supported.139672/

Comment: Did you try: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');`, or another encoding? See: https://php.watch/articles/curl-php-accept-encoding-compression

Comment: The above PHP is missing terminating semi-colons. If you share incomplete fragments of your code it is hard to know if these anomalies are causing errors or not. Please add actual code or at least ensure that what you add is syntactically valid to avoid people wasting time

Comment: @KIKOSoftware It's rather confusing, but "transfer encoding" and "content encoding" are separate features of HTTP. In this case, the server is rejecting "chunked transfer encoding", which is a mandatory part of the HTTP/1.1 spec used to break up the request or response into arbitrary sized "chunks" to be processed as a stream. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding and  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding